# Rotation around point in python (matrices)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pygame

My teacher is not very good at relating math to code, so I was unable to figure this out from the lectures.

In pygame(teacher wants us to use pygame+numpy for this assignment) I am supposed to rotate an object(image of planet) around a point(sun) by using matrices. I have found multiple ways to do this without matrices, but since we were specifically asked to do it with matrices, those are useless.

I can't quite figure out how to change the center of my planet based on a matrix.
Any pointers/hints. I want to do the programming myself to learn, so all I need is some pointers on how its done. Under is my current attempt.

EDIT:
For the record, I know that to rotate around a point you have to move as if you were moving the point to origin, rotate then move back same distance. I just need to know how to do this in code.

```
import sys,pygame, numpy, time
from math import *

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1280, 720
black = 0,0,0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

sun = pygame.image.load("sun.png")
sun.convert_alpha()
sunRect = sun.get_rect()
#Placing the sun to the left in the window
sunRect = sunRect.move(20,200)

#creating another object and placing it more to the right of the sun
osuni = sun
osuni = pygame.transform.scale(osuni,(40,40))
osun = sun.get_rect()
osun = osun.move(400,300)
osua = numpy.array([400,300])

#move object to center of sun
move = numpy.array([[1,0,-20],[0,1,-200],[0,0,1]])
#move object back
back = numpy.array([[1,0,20],[0,1,200],[0,0,1]])
#rotate object by 1 degree(for smooth movement)
rotate = numpy.array([[numpy.cos(1),numpy.sin(1),0],[-numpy.sin(1),numpy.cos(1),0],[0,0,1]])
#combinex matrix for simplicity
movement = numpy.dot(back,numpy.dot(rotate,move))

#standard pygame loop
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    #should move the object here
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(sun,sunRect)
    screen.blit(osuni,osun)
    pygame.display.flip();
```

Comment: For closure, this issue has been solved and i have finished the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand **matrix based movement** you have to think on the `coordinates` of your object as one matrix by itself, placing the coordinates verticaly.

Then, there is the **transformation matrix** based on the kind of transformation you want to apply (move, rotate, etc.)

After you have both, you make a **matrix multiplication** (coords by transformation matrix) and get as result the `new coordinates` (verticaly again).

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation) you can see the transformation matrix for a rotation **on the origin** and further explanations on the use of transformation matrices.

Notice that `Pygame` uses the inverted `y` axis, so, as the linked note explains, you should swap the matrices to get the rotation clockwise or counter-clockwise as intended.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for